# Git: Undoing rewrite of history?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a problem with the following situation:

- several commits are pushed to a remote (our codereview system)
- developer has rewritten history (edited some commit during a rebase) locally
- when attempting to push again, codereview does not accept it (as this change can already haved passed review)

How can I 'reset' a -single- commit to what is in this remote?

The modified commit is not always HEAD, so I cannot simply do 'git reset --hard HEAD^ && git pull'.

edit:

Preferably the diff between the two versions are created as a new commit, but it is not really a necessity.

Comment: What do you mean with reset? remove the commit? if so, have a look at `git rebase` particularly `git rebase -i the-commit-id^`

Comment: @fajran: No I dont wan't to remove the commit. I want to make it exactly the same as the commit in my remote.

Comment: So you want your branch exactly the same as the remote? You can `fetch` the remote and then `branch` it.

Comment: @fajran: no, just one commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the reflog with:

```
git reflog
```

Then pick the HEAD that corresponds to the commit of your choice, e.g.

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{5}
```

would reset your branch to the point HEAD pointed at five commits ago.

Comment: I knew about reflog, but didn't cross my mind at all to use it -during- a rebase. Thank you.

Comment: I can apparently also do a 'git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD' according to one of the other questions on the right here... But reflog seems like the most solid approach.

Comment: The reflog is a life saver :)

Comment: reflog did the job. Didn't knew about it, nice tool. Thx @ralphtheninja.